# SQL Error : Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, jsp, javabeans

I am trying to display only prices that are between ranges specified by two text boxes:

**Java class:**

```
 public Collection<Product> getRange(Double range1, Double range2){
    try {
        // re-use the getProductCollection method
        // even though we only expect to get a single Product Object

        String query = "Select * from Product where Price >= '" + range1 + "and Price <=" + range2 + "'";
        Collection<Product> c = getProductCollection( query );
        //Iterator<Product> i = c.iterator();
        //return i.next();
        return c;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // unable to find the product matching that pid
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
Exception in getProductss(): java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes and add a space before `and Price`

```
String query = "Select * from Product " + 
               "where Price >= " + range1 + " and Price <= " + range2
```

To avoid such errors in the future you should rather use *Prepared Statements* which are more secure and easier to handle.